# Can Active Directory issue a LDAP redirect to another LDAP server

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have several independent LDAP servers, controlled by different entities that allow anonymous access.

I would like AD to tell an LDAP query to use a different server... like recursive DNS.

Is this possible in LDAP or in AD in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use LDAP referrals to refer a client to another server.

See [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978014.aspx) for AD.